# ¿Resize opened kendo Window?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo window, whose content changes dynamically as it has in one select one option or another. An option causes the content to exceed the size of the window and a scroll is created

Can I resize a window while it is open?

Comment: Did you try $("#Window").width(300);

Comment: Looks like you can just set a new `width` and `height` with [`setOptions`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/setoptions).

Comment: That solution works fine with my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Xufox Your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `$("#window").data("kendoWindow").setOptions({width: 1, height: 1});`

Comment: does not work... does not resize the window to 'fit content'

Comment: Please note that this version we are talking about is very outdated and may have changed the way it works.